# Attribute error while using functools.reduce

Tags: python-3.x, list, reduce, higher-order-functions

I get an attribute error while running this code. Why isn't the result.append(item) being returned in the next iteration?

```
from functools import reduce

def reducer(arr):

  return reduce((lambda result,item: result.append(item)),arr,[])

print(reducer([[1,3],[2,4]]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.append` doesn't return the list. You can use `list1 + list2` to extend `list1` with all the elements in `list2`, so the following would work.

```py
def reducer(arr):
    return reduce((lambda result, item: result + item), arr, [])
```

Comment: oh i see. Thank you so much

Comment: @heisenbaig This is a very good answer that fixed your problem. It would be nice to "accept" the answer.